# eclipse cdt - 2 ways to install it, confused about them

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

i go to eclipse download website

i find Eclipse CDT - a version of eclipse that is **standalone**
in my standard Eclipse SDK(not cdt)
i can do this:

Help->install new software-> then i get a window popup and ask me to give the url 
it looks like this:
[image]

so then you can install it

this is a separate standalone Eclipse CDT : 
[image]

this is a standalone Eclipse SDK:
[image]

my question is:
1.what is the difference between separate Eclipse CDT **and** installing CDT plugin onto Eclipse SDK **OR are they same thing?**
2. what is better? is it better to use a separate Eclipse CDT or just install a plugin **inside** my Eclipse SDK?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is no important difference[1] between the two.

Longer answer: The Eclipse IDE is nothing more than a bunch of plugins that work together to create the functionality for code editing (and other things).

When you go to http://eclipse.org/downloads, you'll see a bunch of different packages.  Each package provides a certain set of features, but this is no more than a convenience so that you don't have to install the vanilla SDK and then install the stuff that you *really* need on top of that.  The php dev will not need the C++ compiler and vice-versa.  But, you *can* install it if you want.  At it's core, the same small set of plugins are re-used between all distributions.

You can compare the different distributions here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

[1]: Actually, the difference is that the SDK includes source code for all features as well as the Java compiler and plugin development tools.  The C++ tools do not include these.